# How to access two Snowflake Stored procedure parameters in the query

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to create a stored procedure that contains 2 paramters and create and copyINTO commands

I want to create a table and copy contents into that table using SP. The issue I am facing is right in the first step where I need to SET a value to the parameter.

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE Procedure_name("Para1" varchar(100), "Para2" varchar(100))
Returns STRING
AS
BEGIN
  SET Par12_val = Para1 || Para2
  SET Par2_val = 'Second_' || Para2
End;
```

I tried using diffent methods by passing type as string in the parameters and tried to add $,@ while accessing the parameter in the code. They didn'twork for me.

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE Procedure_name(Para1 STRING, Para2 varchar(100))
  SET Par12_val = Para1 || Para2
  SET Par2_val = 'Second_' || Para2
```

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a DECLARE block to declare your two variables inside the procedure. The parameters you are using in the correct way.

Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#using-a-variable

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE Procedure_name(Para1 varchar, Para2 varchar)
Returns STRING
AS
DECLARE
  Par12_val string;
  Par2_val string;
BEGIN
  Par12_val = Para1 || Para2
  Par2_val = 'Second_' || Para2
...
End;
```

If you want to declare variables inside the BEGIN END block, you have to use LET: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/let.html